# Android. Как менять GPS координаты на реальном устройстве?

Tags: android, геолокация, ddms

Нужно тестировать геолокационное прилежение, на реальном устройстве. DDMS я так понял меняет GPS только для эмуляторов, а у реальных устройств GPS координаты менять не может. С эмулятором под 4 андройд работать тихий ужас из-за тормозов. Неужели с телефоном по улице бегать?)

Comment: В опциях разработчика разрешить фиктивные местоположения и использовать программу вроде fake GPS location на устройстве.

Comment: Fake GPS location это приложение в GooglePlay?

Comment: На Genymotion все идеально шустро работает

Comment: Как бы это банально не звучало, но да - Fake GPS скорее всего вам подойдет. и да то приложение из гуглплей

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо pavlofff ответевшему "В опциях разработчика разрешить фиктивные местоположения и использовать программу вроде fake GPS location на устройстве". Опять покупка квадрокоптера откладывается.